# Functional javascript samples with Jquery, Guru of functional js

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, functional-programming

Are there any open source proejcts or guidelines of using javascript in functional programming way.
I look at open source projects with using of underscore.js, wu.js, osteele [dot] com or another functional js library
Are there any best practices for using  functional javascript.

Can you recomment blogs of functional javascript guru.

Comment: read any book on LISP, haskell or scheme. Functional paradigm is a paradigm it can be applied to any language (with first class functions or without if you enjoy pain). A good example might be the [Backbone.js annotated source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've revised, osteele dot com is very good. Here you have some other useful links that will help you:

- [Eloquent Javascript, Chapter 6: Functional Programming](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html)
- [High Order Javascript](http://interglacial.com/hoj/hoj.html)

Comment: thanks i will look your links High Order javascript very intresting article

Answer (score 0):

Also check out this library and its documentation:

- http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/